# Getting the error 'Call to undefined method PDOStatement::store_result()'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP code for accessing all the servers owned by a user on my control panel, if they have multiple servers this will obviously require multiple rows being returned, but I currently cannot seem to be able to return multiple rows.

So far I have this as my code;

```
    $nquery = "CALL `controlpanel`.`sp_getUsersServers`($userid);"; 
    $servers=array();
    try{
        $serverrows = $db->prepare($nquery);
        $serverrows->execute();
        $serverrows->store_result();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($serverrows)) {
            print_r($row);
        }
    }
```

The Stored procedure returns correctly when ran from the MySQL server, and i have managed to get the first row returned in this fashion, but obviously i need more than the first row. Why would i be getting an error like this?

EDIT:
Im using IIS on a windows server 2012 virtual machine, with PHP installed.

Comment: echo your $nquery and paste it to your MySQL server. 
Maybe something got wrong?

Comment: Ive tried that and it is correct, it echos "CALL `controlpanel`.`sp_getUsersServers`(1);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no such method PDOStatement::store_result. I should try connect to db with mysqli driver.

```
$db = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
```

Comment: What do you mean? I'm following web resources that told me to use the sort of format as $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);, how will'$db = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");' affect what im doing? will i have to change my code at all?

Comment: If you crate PDO connection, you will use PDOStatement in your code. These statements don't have store_result method. I suggest, you should use mysqli driver/extension (you should use your own connection data, instead of above constructor arguments ie. $db = new mysqli($host,$username, $password, $dbname);)

Comment: Riiight I see, so PDO doesnt have store_result, whereas mysqli() does, but theyre both still accessed usign similar methods?

Comment: Okay well now i have this `Call to undefined method mysqli::setAttribute() in C:\control\common.php`, I take it im going to have to thoroughly read through the documentation to convert my project over to this.